# How unhide Window in the menu bar? Or how do I reset menues?

Tags: eclipse, perspective

I've accidently hidden the "Window" menu option in the menu bar in Eclipse. I cannot unhide it the same way I hid it (Window - Customize perspective - Menu visibility) because "Window" is hidden...

Is there some other way to reach hidden options, or a way to reset the perspective? Or must I reinstall Eclipse now. (And yes, I feel like a blockhead now)

Comment: This is what's left of my poor menu bar now :)  http://sv.tinypic.com/r/2hok5mu/5

Comment: How about other perspectives?

Comment: If there is Window menu in other perspectives, go to Window>Preferences>General>Keys, type filter as "Reset" and bind keys(e.g. Ctrl+R) to "Reset Perspective". And then switch perspective to Java and hit Ctrl+R.

Comment: Other projects are missing "Window" menu too now. The check boxes I unchecked seem to have been global settings, maybe not under "Customize perspective".

Answer (score 1):

Hì, I had a same problem. Simple, you can reset perspective by right-click on your perspective, then select "Reset".

Comment: Right clicking on perspective button also gives you the option to customize where you can select all the menu items and toolbars you want.